# How can I identify these capacitors?

Tags: capacitor, audio, identification

Can someone please help me identify these? I think they are capacitors. I have no background in electrical engineering. Just trying to learn this stuff as a hobby. This came out of an audio amplifier board ICEPOWER 200ASC. I have no schematic and could not find one that tells me what those are.

First Capacitor:

[image: 1]

[image: 2]

Second Capacitor:

[image: 3]

[image: 4]

Comment: First one is 10 uF, 16 V. Second one is 820 nF. I’ll let someone else fill in what K means for voltage rating.

Comment: Thank you!!! Greatly appreciated!

Comment: the first looks like a orinary 10uF 16V electrolyte capacitor, the second one is a Kemet MMK Series Metallized polyester capacitor, but maybe a older type, as Bv8 is not in the list of devices (at least I haven't found it) https://content.kemet.com/datasheets/F3294_MMK.pdf

Comment: The second (820nF) capacitor is likely to be 63V given the last picture.

Comment: K means tolerance.